# Как по ходу выполнения приложения изменять меню? (android)

Tags: android, menu, listener, drawerlayout

У меня есть боковое меню. Делается оно следующим образом:

MainActivity.java

```
// Methods, variables, etc...

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            mainActivityPresenter.loadMenuItems(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.menu);
        }
    });

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this); //etc...
```

В классе также есть listener

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    this.menu = menu;
}
```

MainActivityPresenter.java

```
public void loadMenuItems(MainActivity mainActivity, ContextMenu menu){
    if(Что-то там){doSmth();}
}
```

Ну и сам файл разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы после определенных действий, в приложении изменялось меню. Я решил реализовать это, посредством переопределения метода onDrawerSlide, который, насколько я понял, вызывается, когда боковое меню двигается. Этот метод вызывает другой метод класса MainActivityPresenter, который и должен составлять меню. Как же это правильно сделать? У меня было несколько идей, но все они оказались неудачными. (Правильно я вообще понимаю, что onCreateContextMenu вызывается при создании меню в данном случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity.java

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            mainActivityPresenter.loadMenuItems(MainActivity.this.navigationView.getMenu());
        }
    });
```

MainActivityPresenter.java

```
public void loadMenuItems(Menu menu){

    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null){
        menu.removeItem(R.id.registration_menu);
    }
}
```

Вроде пока работает!

Comment: `@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    this.menu = menu;
}` Я вообще убрал

Answer (score 1):

Меню (в том числе и контекстное) можно менять динамически во время его создания, на то есть ваш хэндлер `onCreateContextMenu()`, например:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
   super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

Где `R.menu.context_menu` ресурс где лежит ваше меню.

То же самое можно делать и программно, например убрать `menu.removeItem()` или добавить `menu.addItem()`

Если речь идет об [Options Menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu)  то там немного посложнее, надо модифицировать в хэндлере `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` - в остальном все то же...

Comment: Спасибо. проблема уже решена, но думаю вашим вариантом тоже можно воспользоваться)